# In Jazz, on a minor chord symbol like "C-" - does one play the 6, the 7, or the major 7?

Tags: chords, jazz

When I see a major chord symbol like `C` that does not specify the sixth/seventh, I mostly treat it as `C6` or `CMaj7` when accompanying.

I am however unsure about sixth/seventh-less minor chord symbols like `C-`. **Is there a rule of thumb for this?**

The results of my research so far:
The iReal Pro app avoids 6, Maj7 and 7 altogether for this chord when accompanying (but it does use 9 and 11), however the scales it suggests for such a chord are - in that order:

1. Dorian
2. Aeolian
3. Pentatonic Minor
4. Phrygian
5. Blues
6. Melodic Minor
7. Harmonic Minor
8. Bebop Minor

All have a "7" in their scale, except for 6. and 7., which contain a major 7 instead.

Comment: I quite often use Cm(add2) instead. There's nothing to say it's imperative the added note is either 6 or 7 - of any kind.

Comment: @Tim Thanks. So you - like iReal Pro - don't play 6, 7, or major 7. (But you add the 9. Btw I don't remember having seen add2 before).

Comment: Cm (add2) or Cm (add9). I just happen to like the more intense sound of the three notes (C, D, Eb) close rather than spread. Actually played a few in 'Good Times' at a gig last night!

Comment: C can be played as a C. I have played Whispering with a simple C chord and it worked. Jazz is not always about adding the 6 or 7 to a chord! People think a simple chord is not ok in Jazz but it can be. Some people think that adding a 6 or 7 to a chord makes it more jazzy but I don't agree. Jazz is more about the other stuff going on. You can take a sinple three chord tune and make it jazzy without changing the harmony at all. West end blues has a sinpler harmony but is still considered jazz.

Comment: @harryjansson - there are several different 'Whispering' songs out there. The one I think of, and have played for yrs, has always only had a C maj. start, but the OP is asking about Cm - so no help, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you feel the need to play a fourth note on top of the minor triad, it will depend mainly on what else is going on. either 6 or m7 will work well, maj.7 very rarely, unless it's a transitionary chord between simple m and m7. So, simple answer, either will do, circumstances will dictate.

Rather like sometimes in major, C▵ will work better than the (non-diatonic, but still a '7th') C7. There is no 'one fits all'.

There's also an 'add2' (or even 'add9') extension, which probably works in far more situations than choosing one or other of your '7' options.

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal rule of thumb. You need to look at the melody notes, and at the neighboring chords, perhaps at the whole composition.

With major chords it's simpler: there are three major triads in a major scale. One of them corresponds to the dominant seventh chord, which is normally marked with "7", so the remaining choice is between ionian and lydian, which differ only by the fourth. If you want a rule of thumb, that would be: avoid the fourth, in particular perfect fourth. The perfect fourth is often called an "avoid note" for other reasons anyway. As the ionian scale is a very common base for compositions in a major key (apart from blues), this rule of thumb often works.

With minor chords, it's more complicated. The three minor modes of a major scale: dorian, aeolian, and phrygian differ by 9 (2) and by 6. Natural 9 and natural 6 are both commonly used chord extensions, but they are far from being guaranteed. Moreover, it's more common to encounter songs based on (modes of) other minor scales, primarily natural minor, so even b7 isn't guaranteed.

So the only truly safe bet is a minor triad... which may sound a bit empty in a jazz context.  I'm sorry for not having a better answer!

Comment: Thanks! One point: `it's more common to encounter songs based on (modes of) other minor scales, primarily natural minor, so even b7 isn't guaranteed.` almost sounds like natural minor has no b7 - which is not the case.

Comment: @EvgeniyBerezovsky note in jazz nomenclature the name "natural minor" refers to scale that has natural 6 and 7, unlike in classical nomenclature where there is ascending and descending natural minor.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.   A traditionalist might automatically add 'blue' 3rds and 7ths when he sees a  C (major) chord.   A Berklee graduate might assume the major 7th in C, but use the Natural Minor scale for Cm -  a pity, Cm(maj7) is a really pretty sound!   A 'cool' jazz cat might be unable to resist throwing in a handful of ♭5ths!   I guess the one thing they would agree on is treating ^4 as an 'avoid' note.  And ^2 does no damage.

Context and convention.   Follow the rules of whatever tribe you're running with.  And if scoring for unknown players, be specific.